# How to prevent a CheckBox from being checked?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to prevent a CheckBox from being selected (or to set it back to unselected), when the CheckBox is clicked

How can I achieve this?

I do not want to simply disable the checkbox. I want the user to think it is checkable, but when the user tries to check it... then I will (possibly) prevent the checkbox from being checked and display a message.

Comment: Is this a right way of designing a UI ?? Why you need that??

Comment: I need the same thing. It's for built in help system. In help mode each active element displays help message instead of doing it's action.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        cb.setChecked(false);
        // Code to display your message.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: rather than doing the if statement, you could also just do `cb.setChecked(!isChecked)` assuming you want the message to be displayed every time you click.

Comment: Won't this fail for accessibility features, like Talkback?  I'll have to check.  @gattsbr: That sounds like an infinite loop to me... or a stack overflow.

Comment: @mooing-duck no it doesn't loop or overflow.

Answer (score 71):

Just add the `android:clickable="false"` attribute in the layout xml.

So for me I have:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/server_is_online"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/server_is_online"
        android:textSize="23sp" />
```

and it works fine.

No that's probably not how you're supposed to use a checkbox, but I am using this as a dirty hack in the prototyping stage in lieu of having a nice icon with a green tick for all good, and an evil red cross for end of the world :)

Comment: If you put a `CheckBox` inside of a larger layout that has a click listener then clicking directly on the checkbox will not cause your click listener to fire unless you set `clickable=false` for the checkbox.

Comment: This does not work when calling `performClick()`

Answer (score 14):

Just set it to never being clicked

```
cb.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
    CheckBox repeatChkBx =
    ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
           repeatChkBx.setChecked(false); // perform logic of opening message
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<CheckBox     
    **android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    **android:clickable="false" 
    android:id="@+id/login_access_tick"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

`android:background` for removing on click ripple effect

`android:clickable="false"`  for making it not clickable

Answer (score 1):

this code perfect work for me

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if ( isChecked==true )
                {
                    buttonView.setChecked(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    buttonView.setChecked(true);
                }

        }

    }); //this code through user cant check box check/uncheck
```

Comment: the OP does not ask for network availability. That is not answering the question.

Comment: @zgue , i have improve my answer ,

Comment: Why don't you simply use
```buttonView.setChecked(!isChecked);```?

Answer (score 1):

Just include **`android:clickable="false"`** only, it will work fine.

> ***Note -** Do not include **android:focusable** attribute

Check out my below working example -

> ```
> <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
>     android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="8dp"
>     android:checked="false"
>     android:scaleX="1.1"
>     android:scaleY="1.1"
>     android:clickable="false"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Android CompoundButton class perfomClick() toggles checked state of button.

```
@Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        toggle();

        final boolean handled = super.performClick();
        if (!handled) {
            // View only makes a sound effect if the onClickListener was
            // called, so we'll need to make one here instead.
            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        }

        return handled;
    }
```

You can create a class which extends CheckBox and override performClick() method if you want to manually control behaviour. Because clickable=false did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try View.TouchListener as a listener to the CheckBox view like so:

```
 inner class TouchListener : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            when (view.id) {
                <Your View id> -> {
                    if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //do your stuff here
                    }
                    return true /*To consume click event so the checkbox doesn't get checked, you can set it checked later once you're done using setChecked(true)*/
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
```

*This snippet is in Kotlin